# JQuery ID Selector -what's this behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to jQuery documentation

> **ID Selector**
>
> Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

When you have this markup

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

And you do

```
alert($('#mydiv')); // displays "[Object]"

alert($('#mydiv')[0]); // displays "[HTMLDivElement]"
```

Since we expect 1 element, what is the explanation for the array notation? What makes the two different?

**NOTE: Am more concerned about why we have array/collection of DIV when we only expected one.**

Is `[Object] = Array {HTMLDivElement}`. What is the structure of `[Object]`?

Comment: In most of the jQuery documentation for most selector methods you read something similar to: `Accepts a string which is used to match a set of elements.` As your selectors could always return 0, 1 or more elements it makes only sense to always return a collection. The collection is a jQuery object, containing the actual references to the DOM elements. As such to get access to the DOM reference you can use `jQueryObject[0]`. Even if 0 elements are matched, by returning a 0 length array you don't get exceptions blowing up when chaining i.e: `$('#mydiv').hide()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#mydiv')` //--> displays `[Object]` because it is jQuery object.

`$('#mydiv')[0]` // displays `[HTMLDivElement]` because it is a DOM element

There is a good explanation on why it is an array https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183714/297641

Comment: that link explains it. I was ignorant of this structure

Answer (score 2):

The `[0]` subscript returns a *naked* reference to the DOM element, not wrapped as a jQuery object.

Comment: I'd also add in that `.get(0)` does the same thing.

Comment: and that `[1]` would get the second element in the jQuery object if there was one (which there won't be when grabbing by id).

Comment: is `[Object] = Array {HTMLDivElement}`. What is the structure of `[Object]`

Comment: @Quentin `[1]` returns `undefined`

Comment: @codingbiz As it should since only one element was selected and the length is 1

Comment: @codingbiz — Please read beyond the first 50% of my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery wraps selectors in collections.
In your case you are using an ID. But when you use a class, multiple references may occur.
Keep in mind that this is done to be consistent in all cases.