# Identity selectors in jQuery returning arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Suppose I have a div tag like this:

```
<div id="group-dialog" class="modal-dialog">
```

Now I want to grab it as a jQuery object (in this case so I can run .dialog()).

When I try this:

```
var gDialog = $('#group-dialog');
```

I get an array back (!!).

Why am I getting an array? Isn't the point of having an ID attribute that there's only one? I can see getting multiple p's or .my-css-thing back ...

**Next question:**

I have this array with 1 object in it that I now want to access as a jQuery object.

When I do this:

```
$(gDialog[0])
```

And pull it up in F12, I still have an array!! I thought I de-referenced the array already by picking the first element.

This doesn't seem to help either:

```
var gDialog = $('#group-dialog:first');
```

This is basic, but I run into this problem a lot. It seems like it used to be a lot simpler!

What is the best way to access this DOM element as a jQuery object?

Comment: I may not understand this, but why do you say it's an array? If you use a: console.log(typeof(gDialog)); you get "object" as a return. You can also do: console.log(typeof(gDialog[0])); and still get an object.

Comment: I have to ask. why do you care ? Most jQuery(cant really think of one that doesn't) functions work the same on 1 or 10 elements so i don't see a problem and you can just use  `length ` if you need to check if there's more than 1 element

Comment: @toby: When I run .dialog() on an array I get Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: _I get an array back (!!)_ Nope, it's just an array-like object. And because of that, the output in the console is as it would be a real array.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question, you probabily haven't imported jQuery.ui or something. Also **to answer you're question not problem** look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183704/jquery-id-selector-id-returns-array)

Comment: `.dialog()` is not part of jQuery. This should be part of jQuery UI

Comment: I confirm that everything works if you IMPORT the correct jQuery UI (not just jQuery): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aakkb5pz/2/)

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, yes. I had my dependencies switched around by someone else without my knowledge. Getting arrays back for single elements inconsistently still seems like a major flaw IMHO ...

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1**
jQuery selectors always return arrays.
Selection with id attribute is a particular use case and ideally the result should be unique. However, there is nothing preventing you from having  duplicated ids in a HTML document (although this is bad practice).

**Answer 2**
The following code will get you the first element as a DOM object:

```
var gDialog = $('#group-dialog')[0];
```

Note: you may want to check the size of the return array first.

As far as I know, there is no way to transform this DOM element back to a jQuery object. The standard use case would be to directly used `$('#group-dialog')` and asume that it is found and unique.

Comment: Answer 2- thats the *actual DOM element* - not a JQuery object as the OP requested: *"What is the best way to access this DOM element as a **jQuery object**"*. You might consider linking to [`.first`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) instead

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/). Though I'm not sure it will work with dialog()

> Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

```
var gDialog = $('#group-dialog').get();
```

If you're trying to grab it to use it on a dialog, you can just put

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#group-dialog').dialog({put options here})
});
```