# How can I format values to show double digits?

Tags: javascript

How can I format values to always show double digits?

I want to achieve HH:MM timecode i.e. 02:30

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="480" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange" oninput="myslider(this.value)">

var hours = Math.floor(value / 60);
var minutes = value % 60;
```

Adopted from range slider https://stackoverflow.com/a/48541557/8719001

Full Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h3 id="displayValue">
   <span id="hours">min</span>
   <span id="minutes">hour</span>
  </h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="480" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange" oninput="myslider(this.value)">
</div>
```

js

```
 function myslider(value) {
//var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("displayValue");

var hours = Math.floor(value / 60);
var minutes = value % 60;

var minuteOutput = $("#minutes")[0];
var hourOutput = $("#hours")[0];

hourOutput.innerHTML = hours+':';
minuteOutput.innerHTML = minutes

$('.slider').change(function() {
                var hours = Math.floor(value / 60);
        var minutes = value % 60;
        hourOutput.innerHTML = hours+":";
        minuteOutput.innerHTML = minutes;
        console.log(minutes);
});
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/markusd1984/ec2oavgb/13/

Comment: use string [pad start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) or [pad end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) method.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date) might answer your question.